# Find and replace in shell script

Tags: shell, unix, sed

I'm trying to replace the IP with New Ip but i'm not able to do so

```
Network_settings="1.1.1.1:8.9.0.0:9.9.9.9: IP ADDRESS: SUBNET MASK: GATEWAY"
val=`echo  "$Network_settings"| cut -d ":" -f1`;
sed -ri 's/(\b[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}/  'echo "$val"'/g' Network_settings.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val=$( echo "$Network_settings" | awk -F: 'BEGIN{OFS=":"}{$1="2.2.2.2"; print $0}')
```

This sets the new ip to `2.2.2.2`

This uses awk.

Answer (score 0):

The shell is not going to execute the echo command in this line:

```
sed -ri 's/(\b[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}/  'echo "$val"'/g' Network_settings.txt
```

One way to do it is to use double-quotes for the `sed` script:

```
sed -ri "s/(\b[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}/$val/g" Network_settings.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using `sed`:

```
sed -r 's/\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b/'$val'/'
```